# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA recognize a Python directory in a Java Gradle multi-project?

Tags: java, python, gradle, intellij-idea, multi-project

I have a Java multiproject which also contains some python build scripts:

```
my_project/
├── build.gradle.kts
├── settings.gradle.kts
├── module_a/
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src/main/java/
├── module_b/
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src/main/java/
└── buildscript/
    ├── build.py
    ├── common_func.py
    └── tests/
        ├── test_build.py
        └── test_common_func.py
```

IntelliJ recognizes the `buildscript` directory as Python if I manually mark it as a Source directory.  I then get code completion and can navigate code.  I can also run the tests normally.

But whenever I reimport the Gradle project, IDEA forgets about the `buildscript` directory, and I have to manually mark it as source again.  What can I do to fix this?  Some Gradle config, I assume?

Some additional info regarding the tests:  I have `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/..')` at the top of the test files, and have an Exec task for them:

```
tasks.register<Exec>("testBuildScripts") {
    workingDir(rootDir)
    commandLine("python3", "-m", "unittest", "discover", "buildscript/tests/")
}
```

Comment: have you set build directory as a source in build.gradle?https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html

Comment: @PetrRastegaev That document states that "A SourceSet represents a logical group of **Java source** and resource files". Will this work for Python source? Also, the build folder doesn't include the `java` plugin.